# How to display the "rows" which has value and NULL columns grouped separately

Tags: sql-server

There is a table called 'member' which has 60 columns. Only some of the columns have values; 5 columns have values and the rest of 55 columns are `NULL`.

The problem is that the columns with values are scattered and I find it difficult to search the row to find the ones which have values.

I have tried a few suggestions which I received while posting this question. Below is one of them.

```
select * from table order by NULLIF(value,'') = '' DESC, value
```

I tried below

```
select * from member order by NULLIF(date_of_begin,'')
```

This doesn't satisfy my requirement when I want something like this. I use a select statement and segregate all columns having values to be displayed first and then all columns with `NULL` displayed last.

```
ID Member Name   Age      Gender       Date of begin    DOB     DOC     Extra
1   John         34         M          4/10/2019        NULL    NULL    NULL
2   Jack         NULL       M          4/11/2019        NULL    NULL    NULL
3   David        54         M          4/15/2019        NULL    NULL    NULL
4   Eric         NULL       M          4/16/2019        NULL    NULL    NULL
5   Ivan         45         M          4/10/2019        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I want a select statement which will divide the above example with the below grouping. Age is NULL for Jack, so it should be placed in last column and displayed. This will make my work easier in finding which columns have NULL and which have values sorted.

For example-- >

```
Select * from member where id =2 IS NOT NULL (I need help here in this statement change)
```

Desired results:

```
ID  Member Name       Gender       Date of begin    DOB     DOC     Extra  Age
2    Jack               M          4/11/2019        NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL
```

Comment: Can you include a larger data set, which better explains what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I did try to align your data, but seems something is awry.

Comment: I really want this to make sense but it just doesn't. The explanation and the data just don't line up at all.

Comment: I think you're asking to sort the columns left to right based on those having non-null values coming first, then those with null values coming last, correct?

Comment: @ChrisHackett, that's exactly what i want.

Comment: How would you want columns ordered if for instance your query was selecting IDs 1, 2, and 3 instead of just 2?

Comment: @ChrisHackett, at a time I want query only one ID's

Comment: What you are asking for is difficult because it goes against the very concept of relational data. To do this would require dynamic sql and it going to be a serious PITA to write. This is far more effort than it is worth to do this. Essentially you have query each column of the row you want and then decide if you want to include in the final query. That means for 55 columns you have to write 56 queries. 55 to determine which columns to include and the last one to actually grab the data. YUCK!!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I suggest is to store **one record in n rows**,

n is the number of columns,

then you can order the result as you wish using **order by**
or add the criteria based on NULL values
 I am using the system sql server tables [syscolumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syscolumns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)s and sysobjects

```
create table tab_mytable (id int ,colonne varchar(100),valeur varchar(100));
insert into tab_mytable(id,colonne) select c.colid,c.name from sysobjects o inner join 
syscolumns c on o.id=c.id where o.name='member' order by c.colid

declare @cmd as varchar(1000)
declare @mytab as table (val varchar(100))

declare mycursor  cursor for select colonne from tab_mytable
declare @colonne as varchar(100)
declare @val as varchar(100)
open mycursor
fetch mycursor into @colonne
while @@fetch_status=0
begin
set @cmd= 'select '+@colonne +' from member where id=2'
insert into @mytab exec(@cmd)
select @val=val from @mytab
set @cmd='update tab_mytable set valeur='''+@val+''' where colonne='''+@colonne+''''
exec(@cmd)
print @cmd
delete from @mytab
fetch mycursor into @colonne
end
close mycursor
deallocate mycursor
--Put here your Query to display teh results as you wish
select * from tab_mytable order by valeur
```

You can use also the [UNPIVOT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

But in that use you have to write all the column names, for the solution above, you won't write them in your script

Comment: Hi thanks for this, actually I cannot or allowed to create any table. Only thing I am allowed is to query. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not willing to swear this is worth the effort, but if you only need one `ID` at a time, or at least only a few, this will return only the non-null column values. If you wanted to go to even greater pain and try to pivot it back into rows, have at it, but this gets you a workable result set.

We're using `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot your results, and then dispose of the `NULL` values. You're data doesn't look like a row anymore, but the handful of data points you need are there for you.

Using the `CROSS APPLY`, in order to get all of the column values into one single column, I `CAST` them all as `NVARCHAR` data, so your results are all text fields.

In the example, I returned two `ID` values, just so you could see how that would look.

Data set up, in case anybody else wants to take a swing at this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(
   ID            INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Member_Name   VARCHAR(5) NULL
  ,Age           INTEGER NULL
  ,Gender        VARCHAR(1) NULL
  ,Date_of_begin DATE  NOT NULL
  ,DOB           VARCHAR(4) NULL
  ,DOC           VARCHAR(4) NULL
  ,Extra         VARCHAR(4) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @table(ID,Member_Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_begin,DOB,DOC,Extra) VALUES (1,'John',34,'M','4/10/2019',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO @table(ID,Member_Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_begin,DOB,DOC,Extra) VALUES (2,'Jack',NULL,'M','4/11/2019',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO @table(ID,Member_Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_begin,DOB,DOC,Extra) VALUES (3,'David',54,'M','4/15/2019',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO @table(ID,Member_Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_begin,DOB,DOC,Extra) VALUES (4,'Eric',NULL,'M','4/16/2019',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO @table(ID,Member_Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_begin,DOB,DOC,Extra) VALUES (5,'Ivan',45,'M','4/10/2019',NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Here's the query.

```
SELECT 
  c.*
FROM @table AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('ID',CAST(t.ID AS NVARCHAR(30))),
                    ('Member_Name',CAST(t.Member_Name AS NVARCHAR(30))),
                    ('Age',CAST(t.Age AS NVARCHAR(30))),
                    ('Gender',CAST(t.Gender AS NVARCHAR(30))),
                    ('Date_of_begin',CAST(t.Date_of_begin AS NVARCHAR(30))),
                    ('DOB',CAST(t.DOB AS NVARCHAR(30))),
                    ('DOC',CAST(t.DOC AS NVARCHAR(30))),
                    ('Extra',CAST(t.Extra AS NVARCHAR(30)))
            ) c (ColName,ColValue)
WHERE t.ID IN (2,3)
AND c.ColValue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
  t.ID,
  CASE
    WHEN c.ColName = 'ID' THEN 1
    WHEN c.ColName = 'Member_Name' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END
```

Results:

```
+---------------+------------+
|    ColName    |  ColValue  |
+---------------+------------+
| ID            | 2          |
| Member_Name   | Jack       |
| Gender        | M          |
| Date_of_begin | 2019-04-11 |
| ID            | 3          |
| Member_Name   | David      |
| Age           | 54         |
| Gender        | M          |
| Date_of_begin | 2019-04-15 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Comment: Jake user asked for finding Null values for a table with 65 Columns, the solution you give is for a less number, please take a look at the solution I provided which can work for any number of columns

Comment: @KemalALGAZZAH, the solution I wrote was for the sample data provided and is just to show one method to accomplish the task at hand. The code would obviously need to be re-written for the OP's production system. Your solution seems as though it would work, too.